# How to see which Handlebars version I'm using?

Tags: handlebars.js

Sorry for the stupid question but...

### Where to find out what is the version of Handlebars that I'm using?

What I've tried:

1. Searching for local files containing 'handlebars' string (handlebars.js, handlebars-intl.js) but there is no version in them.

If there is already such question or you think it is too stupid please remove it.